# How can I have a featherlight window escape a iframe and show in the parent?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, featherlight.js

I have an iframe that I would like to have open a featherlight window.  However I cant get the featherlight window to target the parent page, and it will only show in the iframe.

I am have featherlight active in both the parent and the iframe and both are working.

I have tried adding target="_parent" but it continues to open in the iframe.  Any idea how I can get this out?

This is the code calling the featherlight box in the iframe:

```
<a target="_parent" href="//google.com" data-featherlight data-featherlight-type="iframe">Test Click</a>
```

Comment: can you give more detailed code.

Comment: AFAIK using this href link "//domain" sometimes doesn't work on some browsers try adding the complete link change "//domain" to "http:// www.domain.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements:

1. Everything be on the same domain or allow cross domain
2. Parent frame has featherlight.css loaded

Solution:

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Test Click</a>
...
$("#clickme").featherlight({iframe: '//google.com',root:window.parent.document.body});
```

Note:
This is a bug as the docs say that root is expecting a String

> root - String: 'body' This selector specified where the featherlight
>   should be appended.

But if we look at the [source](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/blob/master/src/featherlight.js#LC244) it's not checking what it's passing into [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
    open: function(event){
        var self = this;
        self.$instance.hide().appendTo(self.root);
```

`appendTo` accepts Types: Selector or htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery.That is why we can pass in the selector for the parent document.